# Работа со строками из файла Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Возникла задача работы с файлами. Eсть список IP адресов в файле и нужно каждый IP проверить на наличие в спам-базах.
Когда подключаю файл, цикл проходит по всему файлу, но проверяет только последний IP.

Как проверить каждую строку?

Код:

```
import os
import sys
import urllib
import urllib2
import argparse
import re
import socket
# Requires dnspython AKA python-dns package
import dns.resolver
from urllib2 import urlopen


def color(text, color_code):
    if sys.platform == "win32" and os.getenv("TERM") != "xterm":
        return text

    return '\x1b[%dm%s\x1b[0m' % (color_code, text)


def red(text):
    return color(text, 31)


def blink(text):
    return color(text, 5)


def green(text):
    return color(text, 32)


def blue(text):
    return color(text, 34)


def content_test(url, badip):
    """
    Test the content of url's response to see if it contains badip.
        Args:
            url -- the URL to request data from
            badip -- the IP address in question
        Returns:
            Boolean
    """

    try:
        request = urllib2.Request(url)
        opened_request = urllib2.build_opener().open(request)
        html_content = opened_request.read()
        retcode = opened_request.code

        matches = retcode == 200
        matches = matches and re.findall(badip, html_content)

        return len(matches) == 0
    except Exception, e:
        print "Error! %s" % e
        return False

bls = ["b.barracudacentral.org", "bl.spamcannibal.org", "bl.spamcop.net",
       "blacklist.woody.ch", "cbl.abuseat.org", "cdl.anti-spam.org.cn",
       "combined.abuse.ch", "combined.rbl.msrbl.net", "db.wpbl.info",
       "dnsbl-1.uceprotect.net", "dnsbl-2.uceprotect.net",
       "dnsbl-3.uceprotect.net", "dnsbl.cyberlogic.net",
       "dnsbl.sorbs.net", "drone.abuse.ch", "drone.abuse.ch",
       "duinv.aupads.org", "dul.dnsbl.sorbs.net", "dul.ru",
       "dyna.spamrats.com", "dynip.rothen.com",
       "http.dnsbl.sorbs.net", "images.rbl.msrbl.net",
       "ips.backscatterer.org", "ix.dnsbl.manitu.net",
       "korea.services.net", "misc.dnsbl.sorbs.net",
       "noptr.spamrats.com", "ohps.dnsbl.net.au", "omrs.dnsbl.net.au",
       "orvedb.aupads.org", "osps.dnsbl.net.au", "osrs.dnsbl.net.au",
       "owfs.dnsbl.net.au", "pbl.spamhaus.org", "phishing.rbl.msrbl.net",
       "probes.dnsbl.net.au", "proxy.bl.gweep.ca", "rbl.interserver.net",
       "rdts.dnsbl.net.au", "relays.bl.gweep.ca", "relays.nether.net",
       "residential.block.transip.nl", "ricn.dnsbl.net.au",
       "rmst.dnsbl.net.au", "smtp.dnsbl.sorbs.net",
       "socks.dnsbl.sorbs.net", "spam.abuse.ch", "spam.dnsbl.sorbs.net",
       "spam.rbl.msrbl.net", "spam.spamrats.com", "spamrbl.imp.ch",
       "t3direct.dnsbl.net.au", "tor.dnsbl.sectoor.de",
       "torserver.tor.dnsbl.sectoor.de", "ubl.lashback.com",
       "ubl.unsubscore.com", "virus.rbl.jp", "virus.rbl.msrbl.net",
       "web.dnsbl.sorbs.net", "wormrbl.imp.ch", "xbl.spamhaus.org",
       "zen.spamhaus.org", "zombie.dnsbl.sorbs.net"]

URLS = [
    #TOR
    ('http://torstatus.blutmagie.de/ip_list_exit.php/Tor_ip_list_EXIT.csv',
     'is not a TOR Exit Node',
     'is a TOR Exit Node',
     False),

    #EmergingThreats
    ('http://rules.emergingthreats.net/blockrules/compromised-ips.txt',
     'is not listed on EmergingThreats',
     'is listed on EmergingThreats',
     True),

    #AlienVault
    ('http://reputation.alienvault.com/reputation.data',
     'is not listed on AlienVault',
     'is listed on AlienVault',
     True),

    #BlocklistDE
    ('http://www.blocklist.de/lists/bruteforcelogin.txt',
     'is not listed on BlocklistDE',
     'is listed on BlocklistDE',
     True),

    #Dragon Research Group - SSH
    ('http://dragonresearchgroup.org/insight/sshpwauth.txt',
     'is not listed on Dragon Research Group - SSH',
     'is listed on Dragon Research Group - SSH',
     True),

    #Dragon Research Group - VNC
    ('http://dragonresearchgroup.org/insight/vncprobe.txt',
     'is not listed on Dragon Research Group - VNC',
     'is listed on Dragon Research Group - VNC',
     True),

    #NoThinkMalware
    ('http://www.nothink.org/blacklist/blacklist_malware_http.txt',
     'is not listed on NoThink Malware',
     'is listed on NoThink Malware',
     True),

    #NoThinkSSH
    ('http://www.nothink.org/blacklist/blacklist_ssh_all.txt',
     'is not listed on NoThink SSH',
     'is listed on NoThink SSH',
     True),

    #Feodo
    ('http://rules.emergingthreats.net/blockrules/compromised-ips.txt',
     'is not listed on Feodo',
     'is listed on Feodo',
     True),

    #antispam.imp.ch
    ('http://antispam.imp.ch/spamlist',
     'is not listed on antispam.imp.ch',
     'is listed on antispam.imp.ch',
     True),

    #dshield
    ('http://www.dshield.org/ipsascii.html?limit=10000',
     'is not listed on dshield',
     'is listed on dshield',
     True),

    #malc0de
    ('http://malc0de.com/bl/IP_Blacklist.txt',
     'is not listed on malc0de',
     'is listed on malc0de',
     True),

    #MalWareBytes
    ('http://hosts-file.net/rss.asp',
     'is not listed on MalWareBytes',
     'is listed on MalWareBytes',
     True)]

#    #Spamhaus DROP (in CIDR format, needs parsing)
#    ('https://www.spamhaus.org/drop/drop.txt',
#     'is not listed on Spamhaus DROP',
#     'is listed on Spamhaus DROP',
#     False),
#    #Spamhaus EDROP (in CIDR format, needs parsing)
#    ('https://www.spamhaus.org/drop/edrop.txt',
#     'is not listed on Spamhaus EDROP',
#     'is listed on Spamhaus EDROP',
#     False)]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Is This IP Bad?')
    parser.add_argument('-i', '--ip', help='IP address to check')
    parser.add_argument('--success', help='Also display GOOD', required=False, action="store_true")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args is not None and args.ip is not None and len(args.ip) > 0:
        badip = args.ip
    else:
        my_ip = urlopen('http://icanhazip.com').read().rstrip()

        #print(blue('Check IP against popular IP and DNS blacklists'))
        #print(blue('A quick and dirty script by @jgamblin\n'))
        #print(red('Your public IP address is {0}\n'.format(my_ip)))

        # Get IP To Check
        resp = raw_input('Would you like to check {0} ? (Y/N):'.format(my_ip))

        if resp.lower() in ["yes", "y"]:
            badip = my_ip
        else:
            with open ('tes.txt') as f:
                lst = f.readlines()
                f.close()
                for line in lst:
                    badip = line
            if badip is None or badip == "":
                sys.exit("No IP address to check.")

    #IP INFO
    reversed_dns = socket.getfqdn(badip)
    geoip = urllib.urlopen('http://api.hackertarget.com/geoip/?q='
                           + badip).read().rstrip()

    print(blue('\nThe FQDN for {0} is {1}\n'.format(badip, reversed_dns)))
    print(red('Geolocation IP Information:'))
    print(blue(geoip))
    print('\n')

    BAD = 0
    GOOD = 0

    for url, succ, fail, mal in URLS:
        if content_test(url, badip):
            if args.success:
                print(green('{0} {1}'.format(badip, succ)))
                GOOD = GOOD + 1
        else:
            print(red('{0} {1}'.format(badip, fail)))
            BAD = BAD + 1

    BAD = BAD
    GOOD = GOOD

    for bl in bls:
        try:
                my_resolver = dns.resolver.Resolver()
                query = '.'.join(reversed(str(badip).split("."))) + "." + bl
                my_resolver.timeout = 5
                my_resolver.lifetime = 5
                answers = my_resolver.query(query, "A")
                answer_txt = my_resolver.query(query, "TXT")
                print (red(badip + ' is listed in ' + bl)
                       + ' (%s: %s)' % (answers[0], answer_txt[0]))
                BAD = BAD + 1

        except dns.resolver.NXDOMAIN:
            print (green(badip + ' is not listed in ' + bl))
            GOOD = GOOD + 1

        except dns.resolver.Timeout:
            print (blink('WARNING: Timeout querying ' + bl))

        except dns.resolver.NoNameservers:
            print (blink('WARNING: No nameservers for ' + bl))

        except dns.resolver.NoAnswer:
            print (blink('WARNING: No answer for ' + bl))

    print(red('\n{0} is on {1}/{2} blacklists.\n'.format(badip, BAD, (GOOD+BAD))))
```

Comment: Из всего кода к вопросу относятся только последние пять строк. Зачем же тогда вставлять такую простыню?..

Comment: Если нужно проверить **каждый айпи**, то почему у вас проверка **после** цикла?

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, а где у Вас, собственно, база плохих ip?

Comment: Добавил весь код. Ребята, я только начинающий питонист вот прошу помощи)) Скрипт работает, но только с одним ip. Я хочу, что бы данный скрипт работал с файлом tes.txt и по очереднно доставал с него строку затем проверял в базе, после чего переходил к следуйщей, но почем-то он захватывает только останюю строку и работает только с ней.

Comment: не нужно вставлять весь ваш код в вопрос, нужно наоборот оставить только ту часть, которая непосредственно относится к вопросу. И обратите внимание вот [на этот комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/990587/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-python#comment1671683_990587).

Comment: Проверка после цылка из-за того, что сначала открывается файл затем достается из файла значение после чего отправляет на проверку или я не правленьно рассписал логику?

Answer (score 1):

Вот небольшой пример:

```
with open('ip.log') as f:
    for row in f:
        ip = row.split()[0]
        if ip in bad_ip_list:
            print('%s в списке плохих' % ip)
```

`ip.log` - файл, в котором каждый ip на новой строке,
`bad_ip_list` - список плохих ip